# Error while launching tcl-tk standalone application

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I followed the procedure mentioned in below link to create a Tcl standalone application.

[The Simplest Steps to Converting TCL TK to a Stand Alone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362788/the-simplest-steps-to-converting-tcl-tk-to-a-stand-alone-application)

Once I have my wrapped application, I tried launching it on Unix platform and it throws me `Invalid command name Error:`

I tried launching it with following command

```
%% tclsh char
```

Where `char` is my wrapped application created after running `tclkit` with sdx.kit.

```
%% ./tclkit-linux-x86_64 sdx.kit wrap char -runtime basekit
2 updates applied
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Did you try just `./char`? The end result of the wrapping process is an executable file.

Answer (score 2):

From the post you mentionned:

> ```
> % ./tclkit sdx.kit wrap myapp -runtime basekit
> 1 updates applied
> % ls 
> basekit myapp myapp.vfs sdx.kit tclkit
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> You now have an executable file, 'myapp', that is the wrapped application.

So try to launch it like any executable:

```
%% ./char
```

Comment: I tried wrapping it like 
%% sdx.kit qwrap char.tcl

Answer (score 0):

```
%% sdx.kit qwrap char.tcl
```

This seems to be working fine.